# In cucumber/Selenium when I want to pass the multiple parameter as string I have an issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I am getting this **error**:

> as Step [Enter the Username  and  Password
>   ] is defined with 2 parameters at
>   'stepdefenitions.loginstepdefenitions.enter_the_Username_String_username_and_Password_String_password(String,String)
>   in file:/C:/Users/hai/eclipse-workspace/gherkins/bin/'. However, the
>   gherkin step has 0 arguments.

**My feature file**

```
Feature: Reset functionality on login page of Application

 Scenario Outline: Verification of reset button with numbers of credential
  Given Open the Chrome and launch the application          
  When Enter the Username <String,username> and  Password <String,password> 
  Then Reset the credential 

  Examples:                             
  |username  |password         |        
  |User1     |password1        |        
  |User2     |password2        |
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be more readable

Comment: What is this part in step - <String,username>

Comment: @Grasshopper that was also my concern. I answered below so that he can fix it. I think he confused {string} and "<string>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the specific **feature file's** step:

```
When Enter the Username "<username>" and  Password "<password>"
```

And in the **Java** step:

```
@When("^Enter the Username \"([^\"]*)\" and Password \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void enterTheUsernameAndPassword(String usnm, String pswd) {
     System.out.println("The username is: " + usnm);
     System.out.println("The password is: " + pswd);
}
```

Check the documentation for further information [here](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/step-definitions/).

Comment: Yes I have used